# Is there a specification for the HTML that formatted Outlook email messages conform to?

Tags: outlook, html-email

The HTML that Outlook 365 generates for formatted email messages appears to be a subset of HTML 4. For example, the Outlook-generated HTML does not allow references to an external CSS file -- it does not allow a link element in the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Is there a specification for the subset of HTML 4 that Outlook supports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specification but there is a list created by [campaign monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) that displays support for CSS across many different email clients.With this resource you can either search for it or you can scroll and find specific ones.

Second resource is [how to target emails](https://howtotarget.email/). You can search by device and results display what you can use to target a specific email client.